# How to fix strict error when loading RoBerta using PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, roberta-language-model

Any tips on how to fix this? Trying to follow the basic torch guide here: https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_fairseq_roberta/
but running into this error:

````
<ipython-input-16-53ecab33b355> in <module>
      1 import torch
----> 2 roberta = torch.hub.load('pytorch/fairseq', 'roberta.base')
      3 roberta.eval()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/hub.py in load(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
    362         repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, verbose)
    363 
--> 364     model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
    365     return model
    366 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/hub.py in _load_local(hubconf_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
    391 
    392     entry = _load_entry_from_hubconf(hub_module, model)
--> 393     model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
    394 
    395     sys.path.remove(hubconf_dir)

~/.cache/torch/hub/pytorch_fairseq_master/fairseq/models/roberta/model.py in from_pretrained(cls, model_name_or_path, checkpoint_file, data_name_or_path, bpe, **kwargs)
    275         from fairseq import hub_utils
    276 
--> 277         x = hub_utils.from_pretrained(
    278             model_name_or_path,
    279             checkpoint_file,

~/.cache/torch/hub/pytorch_fairseq_master/fairseq/hub_utils.py in from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, checkpoint_file, data_name_or_path, archive_map, **kwargs)
     71         utils.import_user_module(argparse.Namespace(user_dir=kwargs["user_dir"]))
     72 
---> 73     models, args, task = checkpoint_utils.load_model_ensemble_and_task(
     74         [os.path.join(model_path, cpt) for cpt in checkpoint_file.split(os.pathsep)],
     75         arg_overrides=kwargs,

~/.cache/torch/hub/pytorch_fairseq_master/fairseq/checkpoint_utils.py in load_model_ensemble_and_task(filenames, arg_overrides, task, strict, suffix, num_shards, state)
    409                 raise IOError("Model file not found: {}".format(filename))
    410             if state is None:
--> 411                 state = load_checkpoint_to_cpu(filename, arg_overrides)
    412             if "args" in state and state["args"] is not None:
    413                 cfg = convert_namespace_to_omegaconf(state["args"])

~/.cache/torch/hub/pytorch_fairseq_master/fairseq/checkpoint_utils.py in load_checkpoint_to_cpu(path, arg_overrides, load_on_all_ranks)
    327             overwrite_args_by_name(state["cfg"], arg_overrides)
    328 
--> 329     state = _upgrade_state_dict(state)
    330     return state
    331 

~/.cache/torch/hub/pytorch_fairseq_master/fairseq/checkpoint_utils.py in _upgrade_state_dict(state)
    631                 delattr(state["args"], key)
    632 
--> 633         state["cfg"] = convert_namespace_to_omegaconf(state["args"])
    634 
    635     if "cfg" in state and state["cfg"] is not None:

~/.cache/torch/hub/pytorch_fairseq_master/fairseq/dataclass/utils.py in convert_namespace_to_omegaconf(args)
    387     with initialize(config_path=config_path):
    388         try:
--> 389             composed_cfg = compose("config", overrides=overrides, strict=False)
    390         except:
    391             logger.error("Error when composing. Overrides: " + str(overrides))

TypeError: compose() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'```

Here are my packages for reference:
````

Package                Version

---

antlr4-python3-runtime 4.8
argon2-cffi            20.1.0
async-generator        1.10
attrs                  21.2.0
backcall               0.2.0
bleach                 3.3.0
brotlipy               0.7.0
certifi                2021.5.30
cffi                   1.14.3
chardet                3.0.4
conda                  4.10.3
conda-package-handling 1.7.2
cryptography           3.2.1
Cython                 0.29.24
decorator              5.0.9
defusedxml             0.7.1
entrypoints            0.3
hydra-core             1.1.0
idna                   2.10
importlib-metadata     3.10.0
importlib-resources    5.2.0
ipykernel              5.3.4
ipython                7.22.0
ipython-genutils       0.2.0
ipywidgets             7.6.3
jedi                   0.17.0
Jinja2                 3.0.1
jsonschema             3.2.0
jupyter                1.0.0
jupyter-client         6.1.12
jupyter-console        6.4.0
jupyter-core           4.7.1
jupyterlab-pygments    0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets     1.0.0
MarkupSafe             2.0.1
mistune                0.8.4
nbclient               0.5.3
nbconvert              6.1.0
nbformat               5.1.3
nest-asyncio           1.5.1
notebook               6.4.0
numpy                  1.21.0
omegaconf              2.1.0
packaging              21.0
pandas                 1.3.0
pandocfilters          1.4.3
parso                  0.8.2
pexpect                4.8.0
pickleshare            0.7.5
pip                    20.2.4
prometheus-client      0.11.0
prompt-toolkit         3.0.17
ptyprocess             0.7.0
pycosat                0.6.3
pycparser              2.20
Pygments               2.9.0
pyOpenSSL              19.1.0
pyparsing              2.4.7
pyrsistent             0.17.3
PySocks                1.7.1
python-dateutil        2.8.1
pytz                   2021.1
PyYAML                 5.4.1
pyzmq                  20.0.0
qtconsole              5.1.0
QtPy                   1.9.0
regex                  2021.7.6
requests               2.24.0
ruamel-yaml            0.15.87
Send2Trash             1.5.0
setuptools             50.3.1.post20201107
sip                    4.19.13
six                    1.15.0
terminado              0.9.4
testpath               0.5.0
torch                  1.9.0
tornado                6.1
tqdm                   4.51.0
traitlets              5.0.5
typing-extensions      3.10.0.0
urllib3                1.25.11
wcwidth                0.2.5
webencodings           0.5.1
wheel                  0.35.1
widgetsnbextension     3.5.1
xlrd                   2.0.1
zipp                   3.5.0